# React-native start

Tags: node.js, react-native

Following the instructions for initial setup I stucked when found a red screen with:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge (line 1 in the
>   generated bundle)

After reloading it changes and becomes:

> Unable to download JS bundle

Than I found an advice for typing react-native start into the console. The result:

> react-native start
>
> /local/react_native/android_program1/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:74   const setupEnvScript = /^win/.test(process.platform)   ^^^^^
>   SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
>       at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>       at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/local/react_native/android_program1/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:142:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (/local/react_native/android_program1/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:15:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

I'm using:

RHEL 7, npm 1.3.6, nodejs 0.10.36 and react-native 0.19.

How can I make it work?

Comment: I can just guess but you _need_ nodejs 4.0 or newer (as stated in the guide) for React-native.

Comment: Also, React-native is at 0.19 at the moment. What is "0.1.10"?

Comment: sorry, cli is 0.1.10, react-native is 0.19.

Comment: Can you give maybe any idea how to update nodejs on RHEL 7?

Comment: I would try something like https://github.com/creationix/nvm to support multiple node versions on the same system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. install node js
2. open command promt.
3. type: react-native init projectName
   this command will automatically download all the required dependancies for project.
4. open the directory from cmd using cd projectname
5. react-native run-android

if u face the error like : make sure you have npm install.
then just exicute this command
   npm install --save

your project will run successfully.
hope it work for you..